# Some stupid situation about PK in C#: MVC3 can't insert a new record with passed PK and try to insert NULL as Primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, primary-key, dbset

Good day. I have MSSQL2008 database. And I made a proper model for one of the existing table (VLANs).

```
public DbSet<VLAN> VLANs { get; set; }
```

VLAN Model has field:

```
[Key][Required]
public int VLAN_ID { get; set; } //in the "VLAN" table it is PK
...
```

Then I try to insert a new value

```
_db.VLANs.Add(VLANToEdit); //<-- Here VLANToEdit has VLANToEdit.VLAN_ID == 144. No such data in the table
_db.SaveChanges(); //<--Here I got an exception.
```

MSSQL can't insert a NULL value into VLAN_ID field. But why? I pass a real value but null? What s wrong? I get following message:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VLAN_ID', table 'VMMExt.dbo.VLANs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."  string

If i remove [Key] attribute I got an error in other places about missing key fields in VLANs tables.

How to fix this and force to insert with provided primary key value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# .NET 4.0 MVC Inserting a record with primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748952/c-sharp-net-4-0-mvc-inserting-a-record-with-primary-key)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks deep search on this site!
I found it here: [C# .NET 4.0 MVC Inserting a record with primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748952/c-sharp-net-4-0-mvc-inserting-a-record-with-primary-key)

All is need was to add an attribute into model: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

You may delete my question. Thanks!