# Entity Framework5 Code First Exception "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, code-first

I did try to make sample by EF5 and MySQL.

```cs
[Table("agency")]
class Agency
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int agency_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Agency> Agency { get; set; }
}

class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var query = from x in db.Agency select x.agency_id;
            var new_num = query.DefaultIfEmpty<int>().Max(p => p == null ? 0 : p);

            new_num++;

            Agency a = new Agency
            {
                agency_id = new_num,
                name = "Test"
            };

            db.Agency.Add(a);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

At first. It was successful.
But at second time, It threw the exception in db.SaveChanges().
{"Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"}

With the thrown exception, I traced variable.
agency_id had '1', certainly.

What was wrong?

**Update 1**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

!!!!???????????????????????????

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752692/415682

DatabaseGeneratedAttribute is point!!!

```
[Table("agency")]
class Agency
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int my_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
        int new_num = 0;
        if (db.Agency.Any())
        {
            new_num = db.Agency.Max(a => a.agency_id) + 1;
        }
```

Comment: I thought that the problem is somwhere in querying for max identifier. Is db.Agency is empty in your case at second run?

Comment: That's my guess but try to remore [Required] attribute from your agency_id property.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mapping is not correct. Make sure the name of the id in the database is 'agency_id'.

Comment: After truncated table, it was successful. agency_id is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you manually incrementing your primary key? I see you are using MySQL. Just make it an Auto Incremented column and be done with it. See here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Try this and stop manually assigning agency_id... It may solve your problems.

Comment: I know. but It's just sample. I curious why it throw exception.